# Script turns page white

Tags: javascript, html

so this is a very very simple script. however... every time i run it inside chrome, by the "onmouseover" my entire page turns white. i have no idea why?
this is the script. it was way larger. but i seems to fail at this point...
already tried with other measurements. always the same.

```
 function open(){ 
      document.getElementById("gtext").style.marginTop = "37vh"; 
      document.getElementById("gpic").style.marginTop = "37vh"; 
      document.getElementById("gvid").style.marginTop = "37vh"; 
      document.getElementById("gaudio").style.marginTop = "37vh";
    }
```

maybe someone here can help me.
thanks.
Here my Pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RarJVR

Comment: can you create a fiddle replicating the issue?

Comment: Please add some context code: html, onmouseover event handler, etc.

Comment: here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RarJVR
hope u can help me :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your function to something else like e.g. `openMenu`

Comment: Thank you! that's pretty interesting...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to debug your code (are you asking the community to do it?). For starters, opacity can only take number values (not vh):

```
 if(document.getElementById("gtext").style.opacity == "37vh") {
```